# Adding a default timer in android

Tags: android

I want to create a timer for a default period of time in my android application. 
Help me with this please. My application is calculating the remaining time of a class. If a class start in 8:00 AM and end in 10:00 AM, and the timer will show 30 mins left when current time is 9:30 AM. Can anyone solve this problems?

Comment: So basically you need to update the UI constantly, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a handler and joda time to calculate your minutes.  First the static inner class within your activity.  Static class prevents memory leaks.  This handler will run every minute.

EDIT: *Passing in activity will allow you to call other non-static methods in the activty*

```
    public static class TimeLeftHandler extends Handler {
    private String startTime;
    private String endTime;
    private  WeakReference<MyActivity> activity

    public TimeLeftHandler(MyActivity activity, String startTime, String endTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
        this.activity = new WeakReference<MyActivity>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.d("Timeout", "Timeout thrown from SubjectSelection");
        DateTime now = new DateTime();
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
        LocalTime classStartTime = format.parseLocalTime(startTime);
        LocalTime classEndTime = format.parseLocalTime(endTime);
        DateTime nowRoundFormat = new DateTime().dayOfMonth().roundFloorCopy();
        DateTime classStart = nowRoundFormat.plusHours(classStartTime.getHourOfDay()).plusMinutes(classStartTime.getMinuteOfHour());
        DateTime classEnd = nowRoundFormat.plusHours(classEndTime.getHourOfDay()).plusMinutes(classEndTime.getMinuteOfHour());

        if (now.isAfter(classStart) && now.isBefore(classEnd)) {

            myMinutesTextView.setText("There are " + Minutes.minutesBetween(now, classEnd));
        }

        //call non-static method. 
        activity.get().nonstaticMethod();

        sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0,60000);


    }
```

Then the activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity { 
     private TextView myMinutesTextView;
     private TimeLeftHandler timeLeftHandler;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

      myMinutesTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview); 
      timeLeftHandler = new TimeLeftHandler("08:00", "10:00");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() { 
       //start the handler
       timeLeftHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() { 
        //clean up. 
        timeLeftHandler.removeMessages(0);



    }

    private void nonstaticMethod() { 
       //Your code. 
    }

    public static class TimeLeftHandler extends Handler {
        .....
    }


}
```

For your gradle build in Android Studio in your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.4'
   compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.4'
   compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.2'
}
```

Comment: i see that you are passing Activity to your handler constructor but never used it. why would you do that?

Comment: @k0sh In case you want to call anything else in the activity, you need a way to call a non-static routine within the static class.

Comment: yes, but then in your example code you never used it. because trust me, some people here will just copy and paste your code without knowing what the usage of it.